# JAXB-XJC Xpropertyaccessors

Tags: jaxb, xjc

Per JAXB specification http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html if you want to run the JAXB-XJC compiler, one of the of the extensions/arguments you may pass is -Xpropertyaccessors even though it has been specfied in each of JAXB-RI till the latest one 2.2.5u2 still when I try to run it passing this argument I get 'unrecognized parameter -Xpropertyaccessors' is not specified in the help menu when I run it. It is important for me to have the access levels on properties not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed up with the JAXB RI lead, apparently the plugin is there but not enabled.  The issue will be fixed in versions 2.1.14 and 2.2.6 of the JAXB RI.  I would recommend entering a bug so that you will be able to track the status of the issue.

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/