# How do you specify a XmlAccessorType to be used for JAXB xjc-generated classes

Tags: xml, binding, jaxb, annotations, xjc

I'm using XML schemas and generating java files with xjc to be used with JAXB.
The java files that are generated have the default @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) specified.
I would like to change this so that the resultant java files have PROPTERY access annotated ( @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY ) ) and not have the @XmlElement / @XmlAttribute annotations generated at the field level.
Is there a way to accomplish this via a custom bindings file?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can do this with a binding customization.  However, if you want all of the generated classes from one xjc run to have @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY), you can use the propertyaccessors extension for xjc:

```
xjc -Xpropertyaccessors ...
```

You should use a recent version of xjc because [this plugin was not registered correctly as of as 2.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349190/jaxb-xjc-xpropertyaccessors).